# How to call a method from another method within same class in java

Tags: java

I have two methods in the same class, the first method is`getEventByEventId` and the second method is `addEventUserRealtionMapping`. I need to call the `getEventByEventId` method from the `addEventUserRelationMapping` method. How can I get that done?

```
public EventBO getEventByEventId(long eventId) throws UserServiceException {
        try {
            EventDO eventDO = eventDAOImpl.getEventByEventId(eventId);
            EventBO eventBO = mapper.mapEventDOToBO(eventDO, new EventBO());
            return eventBO;
        } catch (UserDataException uExp) {
            throw new UserServiceException("Error while getting event for event id   " + eventId, uExp);
        }
    }

public int addEventUserRealtionMapping(ArrayList<UserBO> userBOs, long eventId) throws UserServiceException {

        List<EventUserRelationDO> totalAddedCount;
        ArrayList<UserDO> userDOs = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            for (UserBO userBO : userBOs) {
                UserDO userDO = mapper.mapUserBOToDO(userBO, new UserDO());
                userDOs.add(userDO);
            }
            EventBO eventBO =new EventBO();
            eventBO =getEventByEventId(eventId);//I am try that while call method1 but it doesn't work
            MessageBO messageBO = new MessageBO();
            messageBO.setEventId(eventBO.getEventId());
            messageBO.setEventTitle(eventBO.getText());
            messageBO.setMessage(eventBO.getText());
            messageBO.setRingeeUserId(eventBO.getRingeeUserId());
            messageBO.setMessageType(IRingeeConstants.MESSAGE_TYPE_INVITATION);
            totalAddedCount = eventDAOImpl.addEventUserRelationMapping(userDOs, eventId);
            if (totalAddedCount.size() == userDOs.size()) {
                manageMessageService.sendMessageToGroup(userBOs, messageBO);
            }
        } catch (UserDataException dExp) {
            throw new UserServiceException(" exception while adding user relationship for eventId " + eventId, dExp);
        }
        return totalAddedCount.size();
    }
```

Comment: you don't know how to call a method?

Comment: I know how to call a method but I here I want to call and set the return value to eventBO..I don't know how to do that.

Comment: seems to be cyclic recursive method calls? am I stating the obvious?

Comment: Do they belong to the same class? What's the problem in calling a method?

Comment: I'd suggest modifying the question to say that, it's not at all obvious that's what you want. Also, the title needs to be edited, as methods can't be nested, so "a method in another method" doesn't make sense in Java.

Comment: yes it belongs to the same class..the problem is the method "getEventByEventId" doesnot execute in "addEventUserRelationMapping" method

Comment: what do you mean "doesnot execute"? do you bet compile error or run time exception? does it "execute" when called from elsewhere? if you want our help please provide full info on the problem and errors?

Comment: and you certainly dont need to create a new EventBO just before you set the variable to the return valur from the method....

Answer (score 2):

You can call it using `this.methodName()` or directly by writing the `methodName()`

```
class ClassName{

  public void method1(){
  }

  public void method2(){

     this.method1(); // called the first method of the same class
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call function easily but you will need to put  getEventByEventId inside try catch or throw UserServiceException form addEventUserRealtionMapping

if you have infinite loop  it seem that you mapEventDOToBO calls addEventUserRealtionMapping inside it and you are try getEventByEventId again so that it causes infinite loop you